# Bootstrap jumbotron image will not change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm coming back to a Rails site that I haven't worked on for awhile - and for some reason I can no longer change the background image in my jumbotron.

My jumbotron is formatted as such....

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p class="lead">Blablabla</p>
</div>
```

And the css... I'm trying to use the image 'blue.jpg' but it's stuck using a previous image called 'bg.jpg':

```
.jumbotron {
    background: image-url('blue.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    fixed-left: true;
}
```

Any idea where I might be going wrong? I've never had any issue changing the image in the past but even deleting bg.jpg from my assets I can't seem to break the link.

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting that I need to use the "rake assets:precompile" before launching the server - All fixed.